# Использование локальной переменной в функциях Tkinter Python

Tags: python, tkinter, global-variables

Я делаю текстовой редактор на Python с помощью модуля Tkinter.
И у меня возникла проблема в некоторых функциях управления файлами(открыть, сохранить).
Вот код моей программы:

```
# This Python file uses the following encoding: utf-8
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import *
import os

# VARIABLES
version = '1.0'
file = None
file_open = None


# FUNCTIONS
def open_file():
    file_open = askopenfilename(defaultextension=".txt", filetypes=[("All Files", "*.*")])

    if file_open == "":
        file_open = None

    else:
        # Set window title
        window.title(os.path.basename(file_open) + " - PySider Editor " + version)

        # Textedit insert
        Textedit.delete(1.0,END)
        file = open(file_open, "r")
        Textedit.insert(1.0, file.read())
        file.close()

def save_file():
    if file_open == None:
        file_open = asksaveasfilename(initialfile='Untitled.txt', defaultextension=".txt", filetypes=[("All Files","*.*")])

        if file_open == "":
            file_open = None

        else:
            file = open(file, "w")
            file.write(Textedit.get(1.0, END))
            file.close()
            window.title(os.path.basename(file) + " - Notepad " + version)

    else:
        file = open(file_open, "w")
        file.write(Textedit.get(1.0, END))
        file.close()


# PROGRAMM
window = Tk()

# Window
window.title("PySider Editor 1.0")
window.geometry('1300x680')
window["bg"] = "#333"

# Main
# Top menu
menu = Menu(window)
# File
file_items = Menu(menu)
file_items.add_command(label='New File                         Ctrl+N')
file_items.add_command(label='Open File                        Ctrl+O', command=open_file)
file_items.add_command(label='Close File                        Ctrl+W')
file_items.add_command(label='Close All                                ')
file_items.add_command(label='Save                               Ctrl+S', command=save_file)
file_items.add_command(label='Save All                                 ')
file_items.add_separator()
file_items.add_command(label='All Hot Keys                             ')
menu.add_cascade(label='File', menu=file_items)
window.config(menu=menu)

# Text edit
Textframe = Frame(window)
Textframe.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)
Textedit = Text(Textframe, bg="#333", fg="white", font=('Arial', 14), insertbackground="white", insertwidth=3, wrap=WORD)  
Textedit.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)
strtet = Textedit

window.mainloop()
```

Здесь я использую локальную переменную в которой содержится файл, с которой проблема.

Файл открывается но сохранятся не хочет без ошибки:
`UnboundLocalError: local variable 'file_open' referenced before assignment`

Я пробовал внутри функции открытия файла ставить `global file_open`, но это не сработало.

Помогите мне понять в чем тут дело.

Answer (score 1):

Создаешь класс вписываешь вместо локальной переменной переменную класса например

```
class p1:
 pass
 #либо вписать сразу file_open = None
```

Та часть кода где ошибка:

```
p1.file_open = "что-то"
```

следующий раз лучше делать подобие ооп